# Screen is shaking/wobbling in Debian 8.1

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

I just installed Debian 8.1 on my Lenovo Y70 laptop. Besides other driver problems, one of the problems I can't get rid of is this shaking/wobbling screen. I tried to install intel drivers and xorg but it didn't disappear. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u2 (2015-07-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It looks like it may be vid related, 
https://vid.me/9sB5

Comment: Try a new kernel like this one: ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-4.1.0-trunk-amd64_4.1.2-1~exp1_amd64.deb

Comment: Yes! That worked, thanks!! But when i rebooted it, the wirless drivers were gone. Tried to install with the same pkg and didnt work

Comment: Now perform a regression. since you have a 4.0 kernel that works, use the site Jodka gave you and find a kernel less than 4.0 but greater than 3.16, until both devices work, and as a side note try not to find one ending in `exp`. That's short for experimental

Comment: I tried 2 other versions (4.0.0-2 and 3.16.0-4) but none pf these doesnt seem to be installed. When i finish installing either one of them, and thn run the uname -v command to see the kernel version, it is still 4.1.2-1 the one Jodka gave me. Maybe im not choosing the right package? Can you choose it one for me please?  Im new to Linux

Comment: i just had to purge or switch between kernels at boot time. the problem is that there is no other kernel version between 3.16 and 4.0. with kernel 4.0 the screen does get fixed and is perfect, but no wireless driver.